# How do I deal with Identity service in a multi-tenanted website?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a small multi-tenant ASP.NET Core 2.1 RazorPages website that bases tenant off the URL it's accessed by, and accesses a different database per tenant.

I've made a `TenantService` in which it grabs the URL and switches tenant, database connection string etc.

The plan is to never directly access `DbContext`, but to access it via `TenantService.DbContext`.

```
public class TenantService {
    ..............
    public ApplicationDbContext DbContext
    {
        get {
            var dbOptsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
            dbOptsBuilder.UseSqlServer(GetTentantDbConnectionString());

            return new ApplicationDbContext(dbOptsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I load my homepage, before I've attempted to access the database myself in code, I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'
>   has been registered.

I know this is because in my Startup.cs I replace Database/EntityFramework services with my `TenantService`:

```
//services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
//   options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

//services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
//   .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddTransient<Services.TenantService>();
```

But I don't know how to deal with the `services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>() .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();` part in my `TenantService`.

It seems to be triggering an error even before `TenantService.DbContext` is accessed.

How can I incorporate the AddDefaultIdentity/AddEntityFrameworkStores functionality into my multi-tenant site?

Or am I perhaps going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Why don't you use the multi tenant container provides by Autofac?  It will allow you to switch implementations based on a tenant that you provide. It means that you don't have to create exotics TenantService. 
https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html

Comment: Thanks @JonLopezGarcia, I'll take a look. I wasn't aware of it. Isn't this replacing the whole ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection layer with a new one though? I would have preferred to still use default .NET Core stuff, but I'll read more about Autofac